# can't debunk eglSwapBuffers function

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, hook, egl

I am trying to thoroughly track from user-space into kernel-space to find somewhere I can hook my fingers in in kernel-space to pull some information for my CPU driver. While trying to understand the user-space side a little. I am looking to detect frame buffer swaps so that I can track FPS within the kernel (hopefully). I am working with an Odroid XU3 running Android 4.4.4 and a 3.10.9 kernel.

From what I can tell the buffer swap in the egl library is happening in the eglApi.cpp file with the function `EGLBoolean eglSwapBuffers(EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface draw)` pasted below. Now my problem is that I cannot understand how this function is working. It appears to me to call itself recursively as following the `return s->cnx->egl.eglSwapBuffers(dp->disp.dpy, s->surface)` points me back to the same function due to

```
struct egl_t {
    #include "EGL/egl_entries.in"
};
```

and from the source then

```
#define EGL_ENTRY(_r, _api, ...) #_api, 
EGL_ENTRY(EGLBoolean, eglSwapBuffers, EGLDisplay, EGLSurface)
```

The complete function (minus trace stuff) pasted from the source file **eglApi.cpp**

```
EGLBoolean eglSwapBuffers(EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface draw)
{
    ATRACE_CALL();
    clearError();

    const egl_display_ptr dp = validate_display(dpy);
    if (!dp) return EGL_FALSE;

    SurfaceRef _s(dp.get(), draw);
    if (!_s.get())
        return setError(EGL_BAD_SURFACE, EGL_FALSE);

#if EGL_TRACE
    ...
#endif

    egl_surface_t const * const s = get_surface(draw);

    if (CC_UNLIKELY(dp->traceGpuCompletion)) {
        EGLSyncKHR sync = eglCreateSyncKHR(dpy, EGL_SYNC_FENCE_KHR, NULL);
        if (sync != EGL_NO_SYNC_KHR) {
            FrameCompletionThread::queueSync(sync);
        }
    }

    if (CC_UNLIKELY(dp->finishOnSwap)) {
        uint32_t pixel;
        egl_context_t * const c = get_context( egl_tls_t::getContext() );
        if (c) {
            // glReadPixels() ensures that the frame is complete
            s->cnx->hooks[c->version]->gl.glReadPixels(0,0,1,1,
                    GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&pixel);
        }
    }

    return s->cnx->egl.eglSwapBuffers(dp->disp.dpy, s->surface);
}
```

I am missing something blatantly obvious and that someone can point out where this function performs the buffer swap so I can delve down the rabbit hole towards my safe place in kernel-space.

Comment: https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace

Comment: No, it is calling the actual backend implementation for the function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @derhass. I am unsure of how the macro `EGL_ENTRY(EGLBoolean, eglSwapBuffers, EGLDisplay, EGLSurface)` (found in egl_entries.in) evaluates given its definition `#define EGL_ENTRY(_r, _api, ...) #_api,`. I believe it simple creates a string from the _api argument. I have tried grepping for its backend implementation but have not had any luck. Where can this backend be found?